# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; still

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

```py
import mysql.connector as a

class DBHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = a.connect(host='localhost',port = '3306',user='root',password="", database='pythontest')
        query = 'create table if not exits user(userId int primarykey, userName varchar(200), phon varchar(12))'
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        print('conected')


# min\
helper = DBHelper()
```

Comment: Shouldn't `create table if not exits` be `create table if not exists`? When you are told you have a syntax error, *you do*.

Comment: Also `primary key` instead of `primarykey`.

Answer (score 0):

Try use something like this :

```
import mysql.connector as a

class DBHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = a.connect(host='localhost',port = '3306',user='root',password="", database='pythontest')
        query = 'create table if not exists user(userId int AUTO_INCREMENT,userName varchar(200),phon varchar(12),CONSTRAINT userid_pk PRIMARY KEY (userId))'
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        print('conected')


# min\
helper = DBHelper()
```